# Can I retrieve my CoC account using Facebook?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I once have a CoC account. But it was not connected in Gmail. When I checked my tablet one day, some of my apps were deleted including my CoC. When I installed CoC again. I knew I lost my village. So, I was hoping that maybe someone knows how to retrieve it using FB 'cause I connected it in Facebook. I know it sounds impossible. I'm just getting my hopes up. HELP.

Answer (score 2):

Reconnect via facebook again in the app and it should locate your village for you.

I know when it's connected to google services, it asks you if you want to load up the existing village or start a new one.